# Application not appearing in activity chooser whenever outgoing call is made using dailer

Tags: android, intentfilter

What intent filter should be used so that my app is shown in activity chooser whenever outgoing call is made :like Viber and Skype are shown.

**I am using this filter:**

```
   <receiver android:name="OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**with permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

still myApp do not appear in activity chooser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `Activity` as to add it in option list for calling application

```
<activity android:name="Makecall" >
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and for calling to any Number use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` as :

```
Uri numberuri = Uri.parse("tel:"  + edit_text_number);
Intent intent_call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, numberuri);
startActivity(intent_call);
```

Comment: This method inteferes with 911/EMS calls. The broadcast receiver is the correct way to handle calls.

Comment: this is not working in moto 3rd g and sumsung also please help me  :)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I found I need to add action VIEW to my manifest for my dialer to appear in App Chooser. Still looking for an explanation for that.
So this is what worked:

```
<!-- language: lang-XML -->   
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And when I **added** to the intent-filter

```
<!-- language: lang-XML --> 
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
```

my dialer did **not** appear in the App Chooser

Answer (score 0):

You need a Main Activity for the Broadcast Receiver to be registered.

DO NOT use an activitythat intercepts CALL_PRIVILEGED Intent calls. Doing that will interfere with EMS calls. You were on the right track with your example.