# Tapping phone number: I want my App to be in the application chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

It is same problem as in [Android custom dialler on tapping phone number links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534059/android-custom-dialler-on-tapping-phone-number-links/7566258#7566258). I did everthings as stated there.

I want my app appear in the application chooser, when a phone number is tapped.

I have

```
package com.example.editcall;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.d(OutgoingCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), intent.toString() + ", call to: " + phoneNumber);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing call catched: " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }

}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But it does not show up in the application chooser. Any idea?

**Solution:**

As @CommonsWare mentioned below, it needs to be an activity.

Furthermore, `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` does not work, it must be `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`.

And you can forget (for this :-) about `android:priority` and `android:exported`.

So, this works:

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.SearchActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

with this to get the phone number:

```
public class SearchActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String calledNumber = null;
        String inputURI = this.getIntent().getDataString();
        if (inputURI != null) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(inputURI));
            if (uri.getScheme().equals("tel")) {
                calledNumber = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: This question is already been answered here:


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523187/application-not-appearing-in-activity-chooser-whenever-outgoing-call-is-made-usi][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<intent-filter>` is designed for an `<activity>`. You will have no luck using it with a `<receiver>`. Moreover, the chooser only shows activities. Hence, create an `<activity>`, and use your `<intent-filter>` there (perhaps minus the `priority`).